# Distribuição de responsabilidades de um modulo agenda

Tags: php, mvc, repository

Em uma aplicação, preciso apresentar uma agenda/calendario, que é composta por eventos e locações. Estou utilizando o conceito de repositorios, onde armazeno todas as consultas a determinada entidade. Nesse caso, eventos e locações tem seus respectivos repositorios.

Minha pergunta é: quando eu precisar montar minha agenda nessa aplicação, como ficaria a distribuição de responsabilidades para apresentação dessa agenda/calendario?

Atualmente, o controller de agenda, se comunica com os repositorios de eventos e locações, formata os dados e fornece pra view. Segundo o padrão mvc isso está errado.

Seria uma boa prática criar um repositorio de agenda e lá eu me comunicar com os repositorios de eventos e locações pra então montar meus dados e fornecer pro controller?